# Triggering sound when imageView is moved

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm new to Objective-C and coding over all. I've started creating a app where a picture is pulled from upper part of the screen to the bottom of the screen, and it should release a sound at the bottom.

```
#import "TestiAppViewController.h"


@interface TestiAppViewController ()

@end

@implementation TestiAppViewController

-(IBAction)controlPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0,0) inView:self.view];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

If I understand correctly, I should be able to do the sound effect just by using y coordinate and trigger the sound that way. But I don't now how to code that.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)playAudio {
    [self playSound:@"soundFile" :@"wav"];
}

- (void)playSound :(NSString *)fName :(NSString *) ext{
    SystemSoundID audioEffect;
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource : fName ofType :ext];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath : path]) {
        NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: path];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef) pathURL, &audioEffect);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(audioEffect);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"error, file not found: %@", path);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how to use this code. As said, total newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

Kaisa Koivisto, Indra's point correct for playing sound. i have try that's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code

```
-(IBAction)controlPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
  CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
  recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
  [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0,0) inView:self.view];
  if(translation.y + recognizer.frame.size.height == self.view.frame.size.height)
   //now the image is in bottom of the view.
  {
     [self playaudio];
  }
}
```